# Как объяснить обособление приложений в рассказе Тургенева?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

*Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт один мне знакомый человек, **молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке,** Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин* (Т.)

1) **Объяснение пунктуации у Розенталя не очень понятно**: "в дореволюционной России гвардейскими офицерами были, как правило, помещики-дворяне". Ну и что?

К тому же он объясняет только однородность двух приложений, но не их обособление.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=99#pp99

2) Другой возможный вариант:

*Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт **один мне знакомый человек, молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке** Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин* (здесь **необособленный** однородный ряд приложений перед именем собственным, что допускается).

3) И вопрос: **Как объяснить знаки препинания у Тургенева?**

4) **Примечание**

Обособление однородных и неоднородных приложений  действительно **тема не из простых.**

Как мне кажется, теория в правилах дается формально, применить ее к практическим примерам не всегда удается. Тем не менее в классических текстах знаки препинания кажутся вполне обоснованными. Так что же, надо ставить запятые не по правилам, но тогда как?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, я полагаю, ответ на вопрос носит исторический характер. Как сказал Розенталь, малые помещики действительно являлись гвардейскими офицерами. Сначала меня несколько смутило это объяснение, но потом я всё же, на мой взгляд, понял смысл этих слов. Трудность состоит в том, что мышление Тургенева, как и всех его современников, было отличным от нашего. Приведу пример:

*Виктор, победитель девяноста семи олимпиад, настоящий гений, поразил весь мир*

Теперь перейдем к главному, а именно к разбору данного предложения. Что мы можем сказать о победителе девяноста семи олимпиад? По-моему, любой ответит: "Да это же гений!" Не уверен в очевидности своего примера, но всё же проведу параллель: для людей времени Тургенева малый помещик автоматически присваивался к гвардейцам — точно так же и мы присваиваем победителю большого числа олимпиад титул гения. В общем, данное сочетание будет являться уточнением, как я считаю. Запятая тут может ставиться только на этом основании.

Comment: Я, пожалуй, не соглашусь с Розенталем и с Вами. В заданном предложении определяемым словом является сочетание с неопределенным значением  «один мне знакомый человек», а все приложения стоят после него. Поэтому они однозначно обособляются и приобретают статус однородных,  даже если  по смыслу  таковыми не являются (произношение с перечислительной интонацией).

Comment: В этом случае их значения сближаются, так как раскрывают одну общую тему: кем же был этот «один человек».  А далее перечисляются все его характеристики, в том числе имя. Поэтому  не нужно искать однородность там, где ее нет. 
Но почему не подходит вариант с тремя однородными приложениями перед именем собственным?  Я думаю, что первое приложение с неопределенным значением не вписывается в общий однородный ряд (его приходится выделять и пояснять).

В любом случае спасибо Вам за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь этим поясняет, почему в данном примере приложения *однородны* и разделяются запятой. *Обособление* же приложений рассматривается позже, в параграфе 19:

> *Обособляется распространенное приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному
>   существительному*
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

В нашем случае распространенные однородные приложения отнесены к нарицательному существительному *человек*.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Что я могу возразить? Розенталь в этой теме перечисляет возможные варианты (приложение после имени собственного ТОЖЕ может обособляться).  У нас в конце ряда находится имя собственное, и оно может иметь при себе НЕОБОСОБЛЕННЫЙ ряд приложений, такая грамматика тоже возможна. Но нужно выбрать  и обосновать тот вариант, который подходит по СМЫСЛУ. То есть общее решение такое: 1) определить возможные грамматические варианты (я вижу два варианта); б) определить тот, который подходит к данному тексту.